# Finding f(x) functions.

Tags: functions

The question is:
Let $f(x) = 4x - 2$ and $g(x) = -2x^2 + 8$
a. Find $f^{-1} (x)$.
Do I do this by switching the y and x and solving?
b. Find $(f \circ g)(1) $ 
How does this work? Don’t you solve one function and put it into the other?

Comment: $a)$ Yes, this is exactly what you have to do.

Comment: $b)$ Calculate $g(1)$ and insert this value into $f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

yes You have to switch x and y
after switching x and y
$$x=\frac{y+2}{4}$$ 
thus $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+2}{4}$$

for second you want to find $fog(1)$

but lets find fog(x)
$$fog(x)=f(g(x))$$
which means put g(x) in place of x(where ever x appears) in function f(x).

so $$fog(x)=4g(x)-2$$

so $$fog(x)=4(-2x^2+8)-2=-8x^2+30$$
 you want to find fog(1) thus put $x=1$

$$fog(1)=-8+30=22$$

Comment: You can produce $f \circ g$ by typing f \circ g when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

$y = 4x - 2 \\
x = \frac{y+2}{4}$

$(f\circ g)(1)\\
g(1) = -2\cdot 1^2 + 8 = 6\\
f(6) = 4\cdot 6 - 2 = 22$

If you want to get tricky, $(f\circ g)(x).$ First treat g as a variable.

$f(g) = 4g - 2$

Then substitute $g(x) = -2x^2 + 8$

$4(-2x^2 + 8) - 2$

And simplify

$(f\circ g)(x) = -8x^2 + 30$